# Does iOS and MacOS support FIDO2 for native apps (Flutter)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webauthn, fido

Apple's Safari browser supports WebAuthn now. However, I couldn't find information on if Apple MacOS and iOS support FIDO2 API calls natively. This is for a Flutter cross-platform app.

References:

- [Implementing FIDO2 (WebAuthN) in Native iOS](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/240267/implementing-fido2-webauthn-in-native-ios)
- [Fido2 implementation in iOS and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72456877/fido2-implementation-in-ios-and-android)
- [Implement Fido2 in Android and iOS using React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71617176/implement-fido2-in-android-and-ios-using-react-native)
- [contrib-fido2-flutter-lib](https://github.com/mojaloop/contrib-fido2-flutter-lib)

Comment: I found this link on passkeys.dev: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/public-private_key_authentication/supporting_passkeys

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I read that page before but it didn't help answer my question.

Comment: That page documents the system APIs which is how I read your original question. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, @Tim. Yes, I was looking for how to implement accessing those native FIDO2 API calls from Flutter. The cited Flutter package supports accessing it from Android natively but it warned that iOS isn't supported natively.